# PHP Reading Login from Textfile (I Know Unsecure) help needed with the reading of the file

Tags: php, json, authentication

This is my code in regards to saving the registration data to a txt file.
However on the login page i then want to read and verify this data so the user can login.

```
    <?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['forename'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $surname = $_POST['surname'];
    $text = $name . "|" . $password . "\n";
    $file = fopen('logins.txt', 'a+');

    if (fwrite($file, $text)) {
        echo 'saved';
    }
    fclose($file);
}
```

above is the code for saving the data, any methods on to read it or what the most efficent?

many thanks

Comment: Using a text file, as you mention, is insecure. It also makes checking a little bit harder. You should learn to use a database, even if it’s SQLite, so that it is easier to log and to check the credentials.

Comment: I see that you are saving the forename and password, and you would like to read this for logging in. Shouldn’t you be also be storing the rest of the details, especially the email address, which I assume you will need to log in?

Comment: many apologies thats my old version ive put through by accident but your correct the fields i have is username,email and password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are reading data from a text file, you can use `file`, which copies the text file into an array of lines.

To check whether your file contains a matching entry, you can use a function like the following:

```
<?php
    function checkLogin($email,$password) {
        $logins=file('logins.txt'); //  read data into an array
        foreach($logins as $login) {
            $login=trim($login);    //  remove trailing line break
            $fields=explode('|',$login);    //  split a|b|c|d into an array
            if($fields[?]==$email && $fields[?]==$password) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
?>
```

Please note that the `?` place holders (`$fields[?]`) represent the position of the email and password, starting at `0`. For example, in your code, if they are added in that order, they would be `$fields[1]` and `$fields[2]`.

The `trim` function is to get past a quirk in PHP’s `file` function, which includes the line ending as part of the line.

Take this as an example of reading data from a text file.

*This is not how you should handle passwords. You should never store passwords in plain text, even in a database!*

Comment: Thats exactly what i needed brilliant ill give this a go :)

Comment: function checkLogin($name, $password)
{
    $logins = file('logins.txt'); // read data into an array
    foreach ($logins as $login) {
        $login = trim($login); // remove trailing line break
        $fields = explode('|', $login); // split a|b|c|d into an array

        if ($fields[1] == $name && $fields[2] == $password)
            return true;
        echo "login success";
    }
    return false;
}

Answer (score 0):

I normally use [`file_get_contents()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [`file_put_contents()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), i.e.:

**Read the contents of a file to a `string`**:

```
$file_contents = file_get_contents("some_file.txt"); # read the file contents
```

**Append a `string` to a File**:

```
$text = "some Text";
file_put_contents("some_file.txt", $text, FILE_APPEND); # use the FILE_APPEND flag to append to a file
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this not very familar with file_append but ill defiantly give it a go :)